# Integrating over a y-simple region $D$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $D=\{(x,y)\space|\space1\leq x^2+y^2 \leq 2 \text{ and }y\geq0\}$.

Evaluate $\int\int_D(1+xy) dA$.

So I stated that $D$ is a y-simple region because for all $(x,y)\in D$, $\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{2-x^2}$.

My book states that for a y-simple region $D$, where $\phi_1(x)\leq y \leq \phi_2(x)$, the integral

$\int\int_Df(x,y) dA=\int_a^b\int_{\phi_1(x)}^{\phi_2(x)}f(x,y)dydx$.

I tried doing this with $$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}(1+xy)dydx$$ but I am not getting the correct result.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need $\phi_1, \phi_2$ defined in a certain interval. What interval is that?

Comment: $[0,\sqrt(2)]$ on the y-axis?

Comment: I'll let you answer your own question: what is $\phi_1(x)$ for $1<x\leq \sqrt 2$.

Comment: I think $\sqrt{1-x^2}$? Why did you choose the interval $1<x \leq \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: What is $\phi_1(\sqrt 2),$ for instance?

Comment: Oh wait. Is it $y = 0$?

Comment: Yes, but there are still adjustments to be made. I gotta run. What you want is $$\phi _1\colon [-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2]\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto \begin{cases} \sqrt{1-x^2}, &\text{if }x\in [-1,1]\\ 0, &\text{if }x\in [-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2]\setminus [-1, 1]\end{cases}$$ I'll help you later if you still need it. If you manage with this, it would be good if you posted an answer yourself, so this doesn't come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I made was assuming that $\phi_1(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ over the entire interval of $-\sqrt{2} \leq  x \leq \sqrt{2}$.

Graphing the region helps, it will make you realize that $\phi_1(x)=0$ over the intervals of

$[-\sqrt{2},-1)$ and $(1,\sqrt{2}]$.

You end up with the evaluation of

$$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{-1}\int_0^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}f(x,y)dydx+\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}f(x,y)dydx+\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}f(x,y)dydx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$